# jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'function' is undefined

Tags: python, nginx, flask, jinja2, uwsgi

I am running a flask server on nginx + uwsgi. When I run just the flask server via `python server.py`, I am able to use `id_encode` function in my jinja2 templates, no errors thrown.

However, when I launch (server.py) via

`uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:8002 --module server --callab app`

It will crash saying that it was unable to find the function `id_encode`.

`jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'id_encode' is undefined`

Declaring via:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.jinja_env.globals.update(id_encode=id_encode)
    app.run(host=host,port=5000, debug=True)
```

What's causing this problem and how can I make the function available?

Comment: why the down vote? If it's not clear please indicate what part of the question is unclear. Please explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the `__main__` block will only get executed if the script is *run* as a top level script.  uwsgi *imports* your module and so the `__main__` block is never run.  Move your `app.jinja_env.globals.update(id_encode=id_encode)` outside of the `__main__` block and everything should work correctly.