# Flask and Jinja2 - Filter is jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'convert_date_to_name' is undefined

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi

I have a Flask web application which I tested locally on my PC. Locally, everything is working correctly - no issues. So, I have moved on and deployed my Flask application on a Ubuntu 20.04 server behind uWSGI and Nginx. The issue I am facing now is, that my custom filter for Jinja2 template is 'Undefined'. I am not sure where the issue is, at all.

**The error I get is:**

```
ERROR:reservationsystem:Exception on / [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/antonio/reservationsystem/reservationsystem_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2070, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/antonio/reservationsystem/reservationsystem_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1515, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/antonio/reservationsystem/reservationsystem_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1513, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/antonio/reservationsystem/reservationsystem_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1499, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "/home/antonio/reservationsystem/reservationsystem_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_monitoringdashboard/core/measurement.py", line 127, in wrapper
    raise raised_exception
  File "/home/antonio/reservationsystem/reservationsystem_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_monitoringdashboard/core/measurement.py", line 107, in evaluate
    result = route_handler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "./reservationsystem.py", line 216, in index
    return render_template('index.html', treningy=treningy)
  File "/home/antonio/reservationsystem/reservationsystem_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 147, in render_template
    return _render(
  File "/home/antonio/reservationsystem/reservationsystem_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 128, in _render
    rv = template.render(context)
  File "/home/antonio/reservationsystem/reservationsystem_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1304, in render
    self.environment.handle_exception()
  File "/home/antonio/reservationsystem/reservationsystem_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 925, in handle_exception
    raise rewrite_traceback_stack(source=source)
  File "/home/antonio/reservationsystem/templates/index.html", line 60, in top-level template code
    <h3 id="h3forFading">{{ convert_date_to_name(complete_date)[0]|upper }}{{ convert_date_to_name(complete_date)[1:] }}
  File "/home/antonio/reservationsystem/reservationsystem_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/utils.py", line 84, in from_obj
    if hasattr(obj, "jinja_pass_arg"):
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'convert_date_to_name' is undefined
```

**Here is a snippet of my Python Flask code defining my custom filter:**

```
#Convert date to name function for displaying it in Jinja2 template
def convert_date_to_name(date, format=r'%d-%m-%Y'):
    date = str(date)
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(date, format).strftime('%A')

...
# here are my routes (app.route()) defined
...

#Run Flask instance
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.jinja_env.globals['convert_date_to_name'] = convert_date_to_name
    app.jinja_env.add_extension('jinja2.ext.loopcontrols')
    app.jinja_env.filters['regex_replace'] = regex_replace
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=False, threaded=True)
```

**Here's the Jinja2 template where I am using the custom filter:**

```
 <h3 id="h3forFading">
{{ convert_date_to_name(complete_date)[0]|upper }}{{ convert_date_to_name(complete_date)[1:] }}
</h3>
```

**Location of my directory with my Flask files + virtual environment is:**

```
# Flask files
/home/antonio/reservationsystem

#Virtual environment
/home/antonio/reservationsystem/reservationsystem_venv/
```

**The structure of `/home/antonio/reservationsystem` looks like this:**

```
antonio@addictionclubrezervacnysystemserver:~/reservationsystem$ ls -l
total 516
-rw-rw-r-- 1 antonio antonio     884 Jun  2 19:35 README.md
drwxr-xr-x 2 antonio www-data   4096 Jun  3 10:09 __pycache__
-rw-r--r-- 1 antonio antonio   57344 Jun  3 10:06 db_reservationsystem.db
-rw-r--r-- 1 antonio antonio   61440 Jun  3 10:42 flask_monitoringdashboard.db
-rw-rw-r-- 1 antonio antonio   18649 Jun  2 19:35 helpers.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 antonio antonio      40 Jun  2 19:35 requirements.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 antonio antonio     163 Jun  2 19:43 reservationsystem.ini
-rw-rw-r-- 1 antonio antonio  119336 Jun  3 10:09 reservationsystem.py
srw-rw---- 1 antonio www-data      0 Jun  3 10:24 reservationsystem.sock
drwxrwxr-x 6 antonio antonio    4096 Jun  2 19:39 reservationsystem_venv
drwxrwxr-x 2 antonio antonio    4096 Jun  2 19:56 scripts
-rw-rw-r-- 1 antonio antonio    1311 Jun  2 19:35 start_everything.py
drwxrwxr-x 4 antonio antonio    4096 Jun  2 19:35 static
drwxrwxr-x 4 antonio antonio    4096 Jun  2 19:35 templates
-rw-rw-r-- 1 antonio antonio      76 Jun  2 19:41 wsgi.py
antonio@addictionclubrezervacnysystemserver:~/reservationsystem$
```

**My .ini file for uWSGI and Nginx looks like this:**

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:app

master = true
processes = 5

socket = reservationsystem.sock
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true

die-on-term = true
enable-threads = true
```

**My wsgi.py file looks like this:**

```
from reservationsystem import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

**My service definition looks like this:**

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI instance to serve Flask web app
After=network.target

[Service]
User=antonio
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/antonio/reservationsystem/
Environment="PATH=/home/antonio/reservationsystem/reservationsystem_venv/bin"
ExecStart=/home/antonio/reservationsystem/reservationsystem_venv/bin/uwsgi --ini reservationsystem.ini

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Finally, my Nginx configuration looks like this:**

```
server {
    server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/home/antonio/reservationsystem/reservationsystem.sock;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/trening.addictionclub.sk/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/trening.addictionclub.sk/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = mydomain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

To me it looks like the service for my Flask web app is running in different folder and then, my template is unable to import the `convert_date_to_name()` function to the Jinja2 template itself (although I'm not sure this is really the issue here. It's just my educated guess.).

Any ideas and help is much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with wsgi.py

```py
from reservationsystem import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

It is starting the application without initializing it. The code under `if __name__ == "__main__":`
does not get executed,

probably you should use factory pattern to create the app and initialize jinja in that create_app() method.

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/patterns/appfactories/

or you can update your file and initialise jinja at top level

```py
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
app.jinja_env.globals['convert_date_to_name'] = convert_date_to_name
app.jinja_env.add_extension('jinja2.ext.loopcontrols')
app.jinja_env.filters['regex_replace'] = regex_replace

#Convert date to name function for displaying it in Jinja2 template
def convert_date_to_name(date, format=r'%d-%m-%Y'):
    date = str(date)
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(date, format).strftime('%A')

...
# here are my routes (app.route()) defined
...

#Run Flask instance
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=False, threaded=True)
```

Comment: Well, it is said to have it like so: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uswgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: Then try moving the jinja initialization to the top just after the app object is available.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean since I have just that in my main Flask file (reservationsystem.py):
```
#Run Flask instance
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.jinja_env.globals['convert_date_to_name'] = convert_date_to_name
    app.jinja_env.add_extension('jinja2.ext.loopcontrols')
    app.jinja_env.filters['regex_replace'] = regex_replace
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=False, threaded=True)
```

Comment: The updated/edited version of your answer helped me out! it's also somehow linked to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24643530/jinja2-exceptions-undefinederror-function-is-undefined

Thank you @Talha Junaid !